# When alerting PHP echo i see "<html>" in the message

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, alert

Strange things happen often. 
The code works fine but when I alert the PHP echo from javascript it displays like this:

"< html > Login başarılı. < /html >"

[click to view the screenshot](http://www.pantuff.com/testing/Mesaj.jpg)

How can I get rid of that html tag in the message?

This is my javascript:

```
var dataString = 'user_eposta='+ eposta + '&user_sifre=' + sifre;    
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "bin/login.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(mesaj) {
    alert(mesaj);
} 
});
```

and this is the PHP:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("pantuff.com","ttoykoc","*******","db_pantuff");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "MySQL Bağlantısı yapılamıyor." . mysqli_connect_error();
} else
   {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM member");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
    if ($row['user_eposta'] == $_POST['user_eposta'] && $row['user_sifre'] == 
        $_POST['user_sifre'])
        {
    $adsoyad = $row['user_ad'] . " " . $row['user_soyad'];
    $_SESSION['username']= $adsoyad;
    setcookie("currentuser", $adsoyad, time()+(84600*30));
        echo "Login başarılı.";
   } else
       {
           echo "Kullanıcı adı ya da şifre hatalı!";
        }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Weird indeed. Try to configure in your ajax request `dataType`.
BTW , why are you fetching all the members in order to find a match instead of using the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I guess jQuery adds it. Can you tell jQuery how to handle the result, and set it to 'raw' or 'text' or so? (sorry for the guessing, I use dojo and there is a 'handleAs' parameter in the ajax post that does that kind of processing for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert($(mesaj).text());
alert($(mesaj).html());
```

$(mesaj) builds a jQuery object from html. Then text or html function fetches the message, where html gets the message with html entities in it, while text contains no entities.

A different solution, as proposed above in the comments:

Add  `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` in line 2 of the file outputting the text, and:

```
var dataString = 'user_eposta='+ eposta + '&user_sifre=' + sifre;    
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "bin/login.php",
data: dataString,
dataType: 'text',
success: function(mesaj) {
    alert(mesaj);
} 
});
```

Comment: dataType didn't work for me. 
alert($(mesaj).text()); was the solution for me. 
Thank you.

Comment: Another problem! Retrieving PHP echo with "alert($(mesaj).text());" was virtually ok. But when I compare the echo I get, it gets messy.